# Jquery getting specific array items and setting them as CSS styles

Tags: jquery, css, arrays

I've been trying to use the name and value of input fields to set the styles on a button but to no avail, it only appears to return the last value and then a letter of the value.

```js
$(':input').each(function() {
   var inputvalue = $(this).val(); 
   var inputname = $(this).attr("name");
   // alert(inputvalue)
   // alert(inputname)
   $(".button").attr("style" , inputname[0] + ":" + inputvalue[0] + ";" + inputname[1] + ":" +  inputvalue[1]); 
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" value="1px" name="border-width">
<select name="border-style">
  <option value="none">None</option>
  <option value="solid">Solid</option>
  <option value="dotted">Dotted</option>
  <option value="dash">Dashed</option>
</select>

<input type="text" value="green" name="border-color">
    
<div class="button"></div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many things to fix on your code.

- Style properties are camelCase on DOM. You have to change `border-width` by `borderWidth`, and the same for the rest
- You have to execute your logic to set style on `change` event handler, otherwise it will never be executed
- Your each logic won't work as it is, I fixed it on my example.

Here you have a working example

**HTML**

```
<input type="text" value="1px" name="borderWidth">
<select name="borderStyle">
  <option value="none">None</option>
  <option value="solid">Solid</option>
  <option value="dotted">Dotted</option>
  <option value="dash">Dashed</option>
</select>

<input type="text" value="green" name="borderColor">

<div class="button">test</div>
```

**Javascript**

```
$(':input').change(function() {
    var style = {}
    $(':input').each(function() {
       var inputvalue = $(this).val(); 
       var inputname = $(this).attr("name");
       style[inputname] = inputvalue; 
    });

    $(".button").css(style); 
});
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/nrotksz9/)

Answer (score 0):

I've merged your styles into an object and then passed that in to the `css` function, to give it all the styles.  I've also defaulted your dropdown to `dotted` so you can see it works, but you can change that to whatever you like.

Finally, if you would like the styles to update every time you change a value, I would recommend wrapping everything between my two comments in this:

```
$(":input").on("change input", function(){
    //Insert below code
});
```

Change your code to this:

```js
$(function(){
   //Begin core functionality
   var styles = {};
   $(':input').each(function() {
      styles[$(this).attr("name")] = $(this).val();   
   });
   $(".button").css(styles); 
   //End core functionality
 });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" value="1px" name="border-width">
<select name="border-style">
  <option value="none">None</option>
  <option value="solid">Solid</option>
  <option value="dotted" selected="selected">Dotted</option>
  <option value="dash">Dashed</option>
</select>

<input type="text" value="green" name="border-color">
    
<div class="button">Text</div>
```

Comment: You'll get a performance gain from using a selector 'input' instead of the jquery selector ':input' because :input is not part of the css spec. But that is not the issue with the code.

Answer (score 0):

This should work.

```js
$( "input" ).keyup(function() {
    change();
});
$('select').change(function(){
    change();
});


function change(){
  var style= "";
  $('.attr').each(function() {
   var inputvalue = $(this).val();
   var inputname = $(this).attr("name");
   style = style + inputname+":"+inputvalue+";";
  }); 
  $('.button').attr('style',style);
  
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input class="attr" type="text" value="1px" name="border-width">
<select class="attr" name="border-style">
  <option value="none">None</option>
  <option value="solid">Solid</option>
  <option value="dotted">Dotted</option>
  <option value="dash">Dashed</option>
</select>

<input class="attr" type="text" value="green" name="border-color">
    
<div class="button">1231</div>
```